# Restore default "mailing footer" in civicrm WordPress 4.2.4

Tags: wordpress, header-footer

Is it possible to restore the default header and footer?

CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages

I edited the header and footer and now when I try to send a group email, I get this:

This message is missing a required token - {domain.address}: Domain address - displays your organization's postal address.
This message is missing a required token - {action.optOutUrl or action.unsubscribeUrl}: 'Unsubscribe via web page' - creates a link for recipients to unsubscribe from the specific mailing list used to send this message. Alternatively, you can include the 'Unsubscribe via email' token or one of the Opt-out tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reset the default to fix this problem.

In your CiviCRM mass mailing, you need to have the following piece of code (tokens) :

- `{domain.address}` which will display the full address of your organization as defined in the menu Administer -> Communications -> Organization Address and Contact Info (`https://yourwebsite.org/civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1`)
- `{action.optOutUrl}` or `{action.unsubscribeUrl}` to allow the contact to unsuscribe to the mailing

Both tokens are a safe-guard which facilitate compliance with the US CAN-SPAM Act.

You could put the tokens either in the footer / header but you don't have to. You could also add them in your email content.

Also, while not recommended, you could deactivate those verification by checking option `Disable check for mandatory tokens` in menu Administer -> CiviMail -> CiviMail Component Settings (`https://yourwebsite.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1`)

Comment: This worked. I was confused when I looked at this page:     http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Sample+CiviMail+Messages    because I thought I was supposed to replace the words in the brackets with my own text. Just having {domain.address} in the HTML header and {action.unsubscribeUrl} in the HTML footer works. Thank you!

Comment: @MelOnary - if this worked for you, please mark this answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a 'restore' but if what you want is what comes out of the box then you can go look at what is on the Demo site as I suspect these very rarely get edited eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/component?action=update&id=2

Comment: That link is to drupal, and I use wordpress, but I used your suggestion to look at support documentation for wordpress. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mel. for backend admin stuff there is v little difference between them, but I will note that in future i could just paste the 'path' rather than suggesting it is CMS specific. BTW it is helpful if can you accept and / or 'up' this answer so others can quickly find useful answers.